# jquery fadein and fadeout works fine on localhost but not on web server

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, fadein

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

jquery is in header section. The script below is right at the end in the body section.

The fadeIn and fadeOut functions are for thumbnails with buttons to trigger the event are part of the thumbnail divs. That is the reason for fade and fade2 ids.

```
$('#fade').click(function() {
                  $('#t1').css('visibility','hidden').hide().fadeOut('slow', function(){
                  $('#t11').css('visibility','visible').hide().fadeIn();
                  });

                });
          $('#fade2').click(function() {
                  $('#t11').css('visibility','hidden').hide().fadeOut('slow', function() {
                  $('#t1').css('visibility','visible').hide().fadeIn();
                  });

                });
```

PROBLEM: This works perfectly on localhost but when I upload the files on dreamhost, this particular function doesn't work. I have other jQuery functions that work fine. I debugged using firebug, and see no loading errors or any other errors.

What am I missing here?

Thanks

D

Comment: Does it give any error in console log?

Comment: are you calling these on document load or just running the script at the end of the page?

Comment: No errors in console log.. I am running it under  $(document).ready(function ()

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
$('#fade').click(function() {
    $('#t1').fadeOut('slow', function(){ //First do the animation of FadeOut
        $('#t11').fadeIn(); // when done, fadeIn the other element
    });

});
$('#fade2').click(function() { //Backwards
    $('#t11').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $('#t1').fadeIn();
    });

});
```